# Hidding the main scroll bar In a page using css

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, hide

I want to remove only the top level scrollbar while preserving a few inside the page.

I found this but it removes all the scrollbars.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  display:none;
}
```

Using `overflow: hidden;` on the body's css seems to do what I want but I'm unable to scroll down the page.

To sum it up, I want to hide only the main page scrollbar while preserving the rest and being able to scroll?

Comment: can you do `body::-webkit-scrollbar`? although I would have a look at other approaches as the previous will only work on webkit browsers.  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try**:

```
html, body {

    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Or**:

There is a CSS rule that can hide scrollbars in Webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari).  That rule is:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

There is a CSS rule that can hide scrollbars in IE 10+.  That rule is:

```
.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

There used to be a CSS rule that could hide scrollbars in Firefox, but it has since been deprecated.  That rule was:

```
.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

Comment: This seems to work so far. I'll check if it doesn't create some problems down the road.